# x64dbg flow-indent style trace logs

Tags: x64dbg, tracing

I have recently been using x64dbg a lot. I am coming from using tools like dtrace and frida-trace on macOS. Is there any way to get [flow-indent style](https://solaris.reys.net/dtrace-options-flowindent) trace logs in x64dbg? Or would you recommend a different tool?

Comment: Since it's an (active) open source project, I'd check out how to provide feedback to the author and suggest it, assuming that it doesn't yet exist (I for one am not aware of it for x64dbg).

Comment: Author of x64dbg here: the trace files collected by x64dbg are in a file format that technically allows you to write your own tools around it. If you’re interested you can come in the x64dbg chat so we can talk about it. However, tracing in x64dbg is in its infancy and currently doesn’t have many friendly features, so it will be quite a challenge.